# How can I fix RptViewer timeout for an ssrs report in vb.net applications?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have been developing a couple dozen reports within an application for a client over the last several months and initially had to fight with the report timeouts in the server, sql, and client in order to get the reports to properly load.

Some time has passed, and we have changed other areas of the code, but none of the server settings, I use a personal machine that has the database untouched by anyone else. When I attempt to view my largest report in app I get this message after 30 minutes:

An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout, or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

If I attempt to load the report in browser using localhost/reports/, as well as from SSRS preview, and both methods load perfectly.

I am developing in an entity framework, wcf hosted context based setting using the RptViewer class and basicHttpBinding methods, I have multiple app.configs in my program and have pushed all of their timeouts to above 30 minutes, I set ProcessingMode to Remote, and ServerReport.ReportServerUrl to the web browser address(localhost/reportserverand) and give it a 24 hour timeout(86400000 ms).

The timeout modifications I have added all fall under basicHttpBinding in this manner(name intentionally blanked here):

I have also modified the database timeout settings for remote connections in SQL management studio, and the settings in the web browser general settings when connection to the reports have been set to never time out.

Are there any timeout values I may have missed? The browser and ssrs preview versions run to almost the hour mark, so I don't believe the timeout is occurring within SQL, I've been running the web reports based off Localhost/Reports, but the system connects to Localhost/ReportServer(which takes a lot longer to load when in web browser). I'm wondering if this might be part of the issue, as even the loading icon does not appear for a very long time.

Can anyone point out any key 30 minute default timeouts that I may have missed that I suspect to be within the report server itself when accessed through code? Alternatively, is there an easy way to quickly locate which parameter is timing out?

Comment: How long does it take to run the raw sql in Sql Server Management Studio?  How big are the tables involved, and how many rows are you returning?

Comment: It should go without saying that 30 minutes is not an acceptable response time under any circumstances unless you're doing a great deal of data processing under the covers.  Is that the case?  How fast should you reasonably expect your requests to execute?

Comment: Sounds like you should take query analyzer to your report to try to optimize what's going on with it. One thing EF doesn't do for you automatically is generate indexes for commonly used foreign keys you might have to go do that yourself to improve the performance.

Comment: The SQL commands are very quick, running the full query takes about 6 seconds if I execute it by hand. I have my command timeouts set to expire after two minutes, but the entire connection is timing out after exactly 30 minutes which leads me to believe it's not a SQL query time issue. We have a system design that simplifies to a site contains many tanks, owned by a company, run by an operator, and then we need the addresses for both. We are grabbing this information for 8617 sites, and to the tune of 20k+ tanks. SSRS returns several thousand pages, 30 minutes isn't unexpected.

Comment: To get more into detail on the SSRS report, it's using some pretty heavy reporting logic to gather all of the data it requires, and cascades down a few subreport levels. The report is meant to be slimmed using parameters but needs to have the ability to generate for their entire database, which is quite large. I don't have the option to slim it down, and due to subreporting it most likely exceeds 6 seconds by accessing all queries individually, but no single query takes longer than 6 seconds. Unfortunately, I just need to bump the expiry time up to accomodate the report rather than restrict it

Comment: I arrived at that 6 second number by manually nesting the queries to return the results, not by running an analyzer. I don't actually have access to that on my work machine, but may look into it for optimizing later. The longest individual query I have is about one second.